# Firebase makes unity hang

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore

I wanted to user firestore in my unity proyect, so I did as in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup). Notice that I also do `db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;`.
I put the firebase starting code in a trial monobehviour in of my scene, in which I wanted to make some database query trials.

```
Firebase.FirebaseApp app;
void Start() {
    Firebase.FirebaseApp.CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        var dependencyStatus = task.Result;
        if (dependencyStatus == Firebase.DependencyStatus.Available) {
            // Create and hold a reference to your FirebaseApp,
            // where app is a Firebase.FirebaseApp property of your application class.

            app= Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

            Debug.LogError("FirebaseApp succesfully created");
            // Set a flag here to indicate whether Firebase is ready to use by your app.
        } else {
            UnityEngine.Debug.LogError(System.String.Format(
              "Could not resolve all Firebase dependencies: {0}", dependencyStatus));
            // Firebase Unity SDK is not safe to use here.
        }
    });
    db = FirebaseFirestore.DefaultInstance;
}
```

Every time I stopped my app and re-played in the editor, unity freezed, and I had to kill the process and restart unity.
Since I commented out the: `app= Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;`
to: `//app= Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;` as I only wanted to use the database, everything is going fine.

Am I doing something wrong? Does it make sense that due to some mistake unity hangs after re-play (first play works).

On the other hand I dont understand why in the docs the code advices to store the `FirebaseApp` in a variable if the `FirebaseApp` class has got an static instance getter: `public static FirebaseApp DefaultInstance { get; }`

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Can you try this `Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Dispose();` in `OnDisable()`?

Comment: Additionally, provide some extra information. Which SDK version are you using and what scripting backend.

Comment: SDK version firebase_unity_sdk_8.4.0. What do you mean by scripting backend?

Comment: @SrejonKhan `Firebase.FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance.Dispose();` in the `OnDisable()` was a very good suggestion but does not solve the problem

Comment: I guess this is a new [issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/1160), it is opened in their official repo. Suggestion is to migrate to an older version or wait for a fix. Not to self-promote, I wrote a [Library](https://github.com/SrejonKhan/FirebaseRestClient) for Firebase using REST API only for own purpose. You can check.

Comment: that was super helpfull @SrejonKhan, thank you very much. I will give a try to the downgrade to check if that was the problem. What does your library bring to the table soas to consider to give it a try? :)

Comment: Well, I decided to write that when I found Firebase SDK doesn't work in Oculus Quest without Play Services. So, I had no other choice left to write a Library utilizing their REST API. There is already another one, but my version gives more API access, Services, and flexibility to integrate into Project. Still, many works to do, so I would not suggest bringing it home now.